# Problem in enabling back-referencing in classisthesis package

Tags: classicthesis, back-referencing

I am using `classicthesis` package version 4.1. In its manual it is written:

> If you want to use backreferences from your citations to the pages they were cited on, change the following line from:
>
> `\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{false} % true false`
>
> to
>
> `\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{true} % true false`

Unfortunately, the compiler does not like setting `enable-backrefs` to `true` and complains by outputting the following error messages regarding the `.bbl` file:

```
Paragraph ended before \BR@@lbibitem was complete
Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
```

I am using the following versions for `hyperref` and `backref` packages:

```
hyperref.sty   2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
backref.sty    2012/07/25 v1.38 Bibliographical back referencing
```

Could someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why those special characters in URLs do not work is the way `backref` works. To quote the manual:

> Sometimes it is not appropriate if the entry is read as argument.
>   For example, catcode changes for verbatim stuff do not have the desired
>   eﬀect. Therefore the scan for the `\par` token can be disabled by
>   `\backrefparscanfalse` before `\bibitem` and enabled by
>   `\backrefparscantrue` afterwards.
>   If the scan for the end of the
>   entry is disabled, then package `backref` does not know where to put the
>   back references list. The list is printed by the macro `\backrefprint`,
>   thus just call it at the right place.

And indeed, the `url` and `hyperref` packages use a lot of catcode juggling to print URLs verbatim, and this is disabled when `backref` takes over control of `thebibliography`.

egreg's solution is to put the desired catcode for `#` back in, with possible negative side effects. So my solution follows the advice in `backref`'s manual. We need to change the bibliography style file for that. But this is a homegrown style anyway, so I hope you don't mind to alter it further.

In function `fin.entry` add one line:

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$ "\backrefprint\backrefparscantrue" write$  %% added
  newline$
}
```

In function `output.bibitem` add one line:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\backrefparscanfalse" write$ newline$    %% added
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

To make this style work even when `backref` is not loaded, we add dummy specifications of `backref`'s macros to the preamble by adding to function `begin.bib`:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{   preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand\backrefparscanfalse{}"   %% added
  write$ newline$                             %% added
  "  \providecommand\backrefparscantrue{}"    %% added
  write$ newline$                             %% added
  "  \providecommand\backrefprint{}"          %% added
  write$ newline$                             %% added
}
```

The just use the modified style, without altering any `bib` entries.

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 3):

I can propose this hack: add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\preto{\BR@bibitem}{\catcode`\#=12 }
\makeatother
```

after the loading of `hyperref` and the options to `backref`. It may have adverse side effects, though, as doing this kind of tricks is usually dangerous.

However, the best way is to switch to `biblatex` that does back references in a different way.

Comment: @@egreg: this works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

The hints in [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/wK_oIj4jkAs) solved my problem. It seems that `backref` conflicts with the urls that contains either `%` or `#`. Using tinyURL can solve the problem. However, this is not a complete solution as someone may like to have the actual url in the reference. I should say that it didn't fix the correct back-referencing.

That would be great if someone could address how we can have `%` and `#` in bibliography while using back-referencing.

Here is a `MWE`

```
\documentclass[
                openright,
                titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,%1headlines,
                footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
                ngerman, american, % Languages
                ]{scrreprt}


\PassOptionsToPackage{%
                    eulerchapternumbers,
                    listings,
                    pdfspacing,
                    subfig,
                    beramono,
                    parts}{classicthesis}


\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers,sort&compress}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}


\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off,font={it}]{subfig}



\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1

\hypersetup{
            colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV,
            breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
            plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
            hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O, %
}   

\usepackage{ifthen} % Allows the user of the \ifthenelse command
\newboolean{enable-backrefs} % Variable to enable backrefs in the bibliography
\setboolean{enable-backrefs}{true} % Variable value: true or false

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\backrefnotcitedstring}{\relax} % (Not cited.)
\newcommand{\backrefcitedsinglestring}[1]{(Cited on page~#1.)}
\newcommand{\backrefcitedmultistring}[1]{(Cited on pages~#1.)}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{enable-backrefs}} % If backrefs were enabled
{
        \PassOptionsToPackage{hyperpageref}{backref}
        \usepackage{backref} % to be loaded after hyperref package 
                \renewcommand{\backreftwosep}{ and~} % separate 2 pages
                \renewcommand{\backreflastsep}{, and~} % separate last of longer list
                \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  % disable standard
                \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{% detailed backref
                \ifcase #1 
                    \backrefnotcitedstring
                \or
                    \backrefcitedsinglestring{#2}
                \else
                    \backrefcitedmultistring{#2}
                \fi}
}{\relax} 

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
This is test for back-referencing. \citep{chdkiller}. 


\bibliographystyle{abbrvunsrtnat}

\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here is the file content of the bibliography file.

```
@misc{chdkiller,
  author = {},
  title = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention. Vital Statistics Public Use
  Data Files - 2008 Mortality Multiple Cause Files}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data_access/Vitalstatsonline.htm#Mortality_Multiple}",
  year = {2012}, 
  note = "[Online; accessed March 7, 2012]"
}
```

If I remove `#` from the url in the bibliography file, it will work. I am using the bibliography style file, `abbrvunsrtnat.bst`, posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106169/23594). It seems `backref` package does not like `%` and `#` in the urls.

Comment: I'm using Zotero, which does the bib thing for me. I had a doi with a underscore. By `\_` in the Zotero Doi solved my problem. There where only 2 entries I had to monipulate. So for small things, and when you in the END of your work and time is running out, this is the best solution you can find!